# Laravel : ReflectionException Class App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

After logging in to my admin dashboard i am getting below error :

> ReflectionException Class App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController
> does not exist

Below is my  `DashboardController` inside : `public_html/app/Http/Controllers/Dashboard`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('dashboard.index');
    }
}
```

Routs file :

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('logout', function () {
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::logout();

    return redirect('/');
});


Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
//Route::get('/about', 'AboutController@index')->name('about');
Route::get('/events', 'EventController@index')->name('events');
Route::get('/events/{event}', 'EventController@show')->name('events.show');
Route::get('/publications', 'PublicationController@index')->name('publications');
Route::get('/publications/{publication}', 'PublicationController@show')->name('publications.show');

Route::middleware(['web', 'auth'])->group(function () {

    Route::get('search/', 'SearchController@index')->name('search');

});

Route::middleware(['auth', 'dashboard'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard.index');
    Route::resource('/dashboard/users/trashed', 'UserTrashedController', ['as' => 'dashboard.users']);
    Route::resource('/dashboard/users', 'UserController', ['as' => 'dashboard']);
    Route::resource('/dashboard/categories/trashed', 'CategoryTrashedController', ['as' => 'dashboard.categories']);
    Route::resource('/dashboard/categories', 'CategoryController', ['as' => 'dashboard']);
    Route::resource('/dashboard/events', 'Dashboard\EventController', ['as' => 'dashboard']);
    Route::resource('/dashboard/activity-logs', 'ActivityLogController', ['as' => 'dashboard']);
    Route::resource('/dashboard/pages', 'Dashboard\PageController', ['as' => 'dashboard']);
    Route::resource('/dashboard/publications', 'Dashboard\PublicationController', ['as' => 'dashboard']);
});

Route::any('/{any}', '\App\Http\Controllers\PageController@show')->where('any', '.*')->name('pages.show');
```

Below is my laravel version

> Laravel Version:  5.8

i have spent hours on this but unable to find the issue , could someone please help me to fix the issue

Comment: Welcome to SO .... can you adjust the namespace defined in the `DashboardController` to mirror the folder structure, with the `Dashboard` part added?

Comment: thanks for reply @lagbox i tried this as well namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard;
 did not work , can you advise if this is what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Controllers you are referencing in your routes are being prefixed with a namespace of `App\Http\Controllers`. Since your Controller is in a subnamespace of this (also a subfolder of the mapped directory for this namespace) you will need to tell the Router about the rest of the namespace to this Controller:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', 'Dashboard\DashboardController@index')...
```

You would also have to adjust the defined namespace in your `DashboardController.php` file as well:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard;
```